# Electron orbital filling order

Tags: electrons

In the p sub shell there are 3 orbitals, 
m=-1, m=0, m=1 
which are listed by axis x,y, and z. 
Some show as -1=x,0=y,1=z
Another shows -1=x,0=z,1=y
Some pictures and text also show the filling order as ‘xyz’ and others state that the z axis is filled first m=0 and then the x axis as m=-1 making the filling order z,x,y

What is the correct filling order?
If I know this then I can figure out the d and f sub shells.
d~m=-2,-1,0,1,2
F-m=-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3
Thanks, HJS

Comment: Your question makes no sense - orbitals don't have "direction" or "number" written on them.

Comment: @Mithoron Well, they sure don't have anything _written_ on them per se, but they do have different orientations in space, don't they? For example, the three p orbitals have different orientation along the $x,y,z$ axes.

Comment: @GaurangTandon technically no. We can define a set of axes around a molecule and then write the wavefunction of the p-orbitals in such a way where it lines up with those axes, but this is more about how we choose to define our basis of states than something intrinsic about the orbitals. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_orbital#Real_orbitals

Comment: @Tyberius You mean to say that if we remove the coordinate axes then all the orbitals are symmetric with each other. Alright, I get it! BUT how does this explain $d_{z^2}$ as compared to the other $d$ oribtals? Surely the former is not at all symmetric with the others even if  we remove the coordinate axes...

Answer (score 1):

There is no order for filling **atomic** orbitals of the same azimuthal quantum number (l) such as px, py, and pz since they are degenerate ie. have the same energy (however they lose their degeneracy in a magnetic field, see Zeeman effect). Therefore, one electron in a p sub-cell can be in either 3 of them and the order of filling doenst matter. For when more electrons are added in degenerate orbitals look up Hund's rule and the Pauli principle.